# mocha runs tests in subfolder but not root

Tags: mocha.js

this is weird I've never had issues with this.  My folder structure is this

**javascript/test/unit**
    - some .spec.js at this level

**javascript/test/unit/features**
    - some .spec.js at this level

I've always done it this way but for some reason it's not working, it only runs tests in the features folder:
`./javascript/test/unit/**/*.spec.js`

and yes they're all named with a .spec.js at the end, that's definitely not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

strange I just did `./javascript/test/unit/` and it works.  That's odd.